# Clicking on an element and getting the ID of child element

Tags: javascript, html, click, stoppropagation

I'm working within a wordpress site. I have an image map that can run scripts when I click sections of the image.

Previously I would click a button and it would show a modal popup but it adds additional scripts etc. The button itself gives no clue to what function it is running, so I was thinking I could run a script that takes the ID of the polygon (image map) and finds the button that has an attribute that matches.

I was thinking something like

```
function popout(popup){

    $('.imp-shape').click(function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
}
```

to get my ID but I think it's not able to get down to the polygon element as it is clicking on the div container, below is the HTML

```
<div class="imp-shape-container">
   <svg>
      <polygon class="imp-shape" id="elementID"></polygon>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the click event onto the polygon should it should only fire when you click on this but it will propogate up the tree. Also, you may need to me more specific than using (this).

Try

```
function popout(popup){

$('.imp-shape').click(function(event) {

    var id = event.target.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

}